# Pytorch - For loop LSTM and Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed

Tags: pytorch

I'm a pytorch beginner. I have a for loop LSTM in my model for some reason. When I train the model in the second epoch I got the RuntimeError like this:
Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.

I tried to use retain_graph=True in loss, but this causes the training process really slow.

My network architecture as follows: LSTM and full connect layer

```
def __init__(self,embedding_dim,hidden_size,batch_size,compare_num):
    super(MultiLayerClassifer,self).__init__()
    self.studentPath_layers=compare_num
    self.embedding_dim=embedding_dim
    self.hidden_size=hidden_size
    self.batch_size=batch_size
    self.lstm=nn.LSTM(self.embedding_dim*3,hidden_size,batch_first=True)
    self.l1=nn.Linear(hidden_size,int(hidden_size/2))
    self.l2=nn.Linear(int(hidden_size/2),1)
    self.allLinear1=nn.Linear(self.studentPath_layers,class_num)
```

And forward:

```
def forward(self,inputs):
    sList=[]
    for i in range(self.studentPath_layers):
        if i >= inputs.size()[1]:
            break
        sentence=inputs[:,i]

        sentence_embedding=sentence.view
        (sentence.shape[0],sentence.shape[1],-1)

        self.hidden=self.init_hidden(sentence.shape[0])
        output,self.hidden=self.lstm(sentence_embedding,self.hidden)

        s=self.l1(output[:,-1,:])
        s=self.l2(s)
        s=torch.tanh(s)
        sList.append(s)
    sVariable=torch.stack(sList,-1)
    y=self.allLinear1(sVariable)
    return y
```

Train process in an epoch as follows:

```
for studentIdList,courseIdList,scoreList,sentenceList,embeddingList,typeList in t:

    model.train()

    embeddings_in=embeddingList.to(device)
    target=torch.tensor([tag_to_ix[s] for s in     scoreList],dtype=torch.long).to(device)


    output=model(embeddings_in)
    output=output.reshape((output.shape[0],3)).to(device)
    train_acc+=(torch.max(output, 1)[1]==target).sum().item()

    loss=loss_function(output,target)
    if weight_decay > 0:
        loss = loss + reg_loss(model)
    train_loss+=loss.item()

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()
    train_num+=embeddings_in.shape[0]
    step+=1
```

Can anyone help me? I think the for loop cause the problem, but I'm confused after tried several methods.